# Genitive case vs. von, when "a noun stands by itself or is used with a word which does not decline"

Tags: genitive

In the page 49 of [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer%27s_German_Grammar_and_Usage), one reads:

[image]

I don't understand the claimed *must* of the author regarding preferring *von* over *genitive case* in the marked sections. For example, the 4th example of the section (a) says one has to compose "ein Strahl von Hoffnung", yet why can one not say "ein Strahl **der** Hoffnung"?

Comment: As I understand it, the author is merely claiming that *ein Strahl Hoffnung* is bad.

Comment: @DavidVogt: I'm wondering why he uses "must", not "should", in his argument if that's just a recommendation. I thought that "must" implies the falsehood of "ein Strahl der Hoffnung".

Comment: @Roboticist I believe the author is more concerned about _good formulations_ rather than grammatical demands.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nope, wrong again.

Comment: @Roboticist In *ein Strahl der Hoffnung*, *Hoffnung* is not used by itself (nor with a word that does not decline).

Comment: @DavidVogt: You just repeated the title (a) of the picture. Can you expand your idea a little bit?

Comment: @c.p.: It is indeed relevant. Obscurity regarding the source may drive people thinking the raised issue (the "must" word which should have basically been "should") is because the source is a low-level one, and the author was not careful enough within presenting his point. If so, people who see the question would undermine the source credibility instead of thinking about the author's logic to put that "must". Thus, I would like to keep the link.

Comment: @Roboticist your link goes to an online shopping page, for the form it has. That's not a link to the book. Don't you think a quote via *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer%27s_German_Grammar_and_Usage* would be enough?

Comment: @c.p. The link is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author seems to be saying that *von* must be used when there is no determiner present to take the genitive case. In the first example we see a null-article, which obviously can't take a case. Here I would agree that you really must use the *von*-construction.

> *genitive with a declinable determiner:* der Bau **der** Kraftwerke; der Bau **eines** Kraftwerks; der Bau **schöner** Kraftwerke
>
> *von-construction whith an indeclinable determiner:* der Bau von **[null-article]** Kraftwerken; der Bau von **fünf** Kraftwerken

But when we look at that final example you were having troubles with, we can actually use multiple varieties:

> *genitive with a declinable determiner:* ein Strahl **der** Hoffnung
>
> *von-construction whith an undeclinable determiner:* ein Strahl von **[null-article]** Hoffnung
>
> *partitive apposition with a null-article:* ein Strahl **[null-article]** Hoffnung

Comment: If you substitute a noun that takes an argument such as *Aufkeimen* for *Strahl*, it becomes clear that *ein Strahl Hoffnung* is distinct from constructions involving a genitive, since only *das Aufkeimen von Hoffnung* and *das Aufkeimen der Hoffnung* but not *das Aufkeimen Hoffnung* are possible.

Comment: I'd argue that your example is actually a *subjective genitive*, which is quite different from the partitive I was talkign about.

subjective: Wessen Aufkeimen/Wer keimt auf? Die Hoffnung
partitive: Wie viel Hoffnung? Ein Strahl Hoffnung

Comment: Is *Glas  Weines* really used?

Comment: Let's assume *eine Schüssel Milch* involves a partitive genitive. Note that *eine Schüssel von Milch* is bad, but *ein Strahl von Hoffnung* is not. So either *ein Strahl Hoffnung* does not involve a partitive genitive or *eine Schüssel Milch* doesn't (or both).

Comment: Or the reason that *eine Schüssel von Milch* is bad, is that you can't replace the partitive genitive at all. That example sounds to me like you're saying *the bowl is made of milk*. That problem doesn't arise with *ein Strahl von Hoffnung*, because that interpretation works here: *a ray made of hope*.

Comment: Given your assumption that *eine Schüssel Milch* involves a partitive genitive, how do you explain that *eine Schüssel der Milch* is weird whereas *ein Strahl der Hoffnung* is not?

Comment: Probably due to the semantical difference between *Milch* and *Hoffnung*. Since *Milch* is a mass noun depicting a fluid, you'd prefer to use it with the indefinite null-article. Context and definitiveness could actually be very important here; *eine Schüssel der Milch, die ich als Kind so gern getrunken habe* doesn't sound wrong to me at all. *Hoffnung*, on the other hand, refers to an abstract concept. It's up to the speaker whether he chooses to use the definite or the indefinite version.

Comment: I still don't get why there is a need to assume that *ein Strahl Hoffnung* involves a genitive at all. Contrary to your assumption, *ein Glas Wein* is used over *Weines* if there is no adjective or determiner present.

Comment: Don't you think it's suspicious that **zero** hits were found for  *Glas Weines* if you run a Ngrams search? Being that common this pair of nouns, this means that pretty much never has been written since 1800, and you claim it's possible to say it?

Comment: Well okay, I've done some reading, and it seems that I am in the wrong here after all. In contemporary language, the partitive genitive really can't be used in the way I claimed. At best, it might be used for a deliberate archaic style in literature and poetry. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed cases where you cannot use genitive and you must use *von*.

Such is the case when you don't have an article and you don't have an adjective:

> e.g. *Ein Angebot fünf teurer Produkte* is ok, but if the products are not qualified by an adjective (*teuer*), then you say *Ein Angebot von fünf Produkten* and not *Angebot fünf Produkte*.

The problem is that due to the absence of the (declined) adjective, you cannot *show* you are using genitive by just juxtaposing (although for other selected nouns you can). Then you use *von*.

Comment: *Ein Strauß Blumen* hört sich für mich nicht falsch an.

Comment: @GrottenOlm Liegt wohl an *Blumen* oder Strauß